# How to retrieve the repository from JHipster spring controller?

Tags: spring, jhipster, spring-repositories

I have a JHipster microservice application, and I've added a spring controller. However, it is generated without a repository and I don't know how to retrieve it to perform data tasks.

This is the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/data")
public class DataResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataResource.class);
    private final DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    public DataResource() {
    }

    /**
    * GET global
    */
    @GetMapping("/global")
    public ResponseEntity<GlobalStatusDTO[]> global() {

        List<Device> list=deviceRepository.findAll();
        GlobalStatusDTO data[]=new GlobalStatusDTO[]{new GlobalStatusDTO(list.size(),1,1,1,1)};
        return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I need to inject an already existing repository, here is the CRUD part where the repository is initialized:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Transactional
public class DeviceResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "powerbackDevice";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    public DeviceResource(DeviceRepository deviceRepository) {
        this.deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /devices} : Create a new device.
     *
     * @param device the device to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new device, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the device has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PostMapping("/devices")
    public ResponseEntity<Device> createDevice(@Valid @RequestBody Device device) throws URISyntaxException {
...
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Did you mean you have no DeviceRepository? Or If you want to include(inject) DeviceRepository in your DeviceResource then you can include it in your constructor or use @inject method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might misunderstand you, but your first code part doesn't work, because, you didn't inject `DeviceRepository` by the constructor. Of course, there are other methods of injections.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/data")
public class DataResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataResource.class);
    private final DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    //changes are here only, constructor method of injection
    public DataResource(DeviceRepository deviceRepository) {
      this.deviceRepository = deviceRepository; 
    }

    /**
    * GET global
    */
    @GetMapping("/global")
    public ResponseEntity<GlobalStatusDTO[]> global() {

        List<Device> list=deviceRepository.findAll();
        GlobalStatusDTO data[]=new GlobalStatusDTO[]{new GlobalStatusDTO(list.size(),1,1,1,1)};
        return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: That was it! I got confused because the generated test had a different constructor and needed to be updated as well